# str_replace match only first instance

Tags: php, preg-match-all, str-replace

A followup question to [Get all text between tags with preg_match_all() or better function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063704/)

Given the following POST data:

```
2010-June-3
<remove>2010-June-3</remove>
2010-June-15
2010-June-16
2010-June-17
2010-June-3
2010-June-1
```

I'm wanting to remove ONLY the first instance of 2010-June-3, but the following code removes all the data.

```
$i = 1;
$pattern = "/<remove>(.*?)<\/remove>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $_POST['exclude'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if (!empty($matches)) { 
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            // replace first instance of excluded data
            $_POST['exclude'] = str_replace($match[1], "", $_POST['exclude'], $i);  
        }
   }

echo "<br /><br />".$_POST['exclude'];
```

This echos:

```
<remove></remove>
2010-June-15
2010-June-16
2010-June-17
2010-June-1
```

It should echo:

```
<remove>2010-June-3</remove>
2010-June-15
2010-June-16
2010-June-17
2010-June-3
2010-June-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [preg_replace()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead:

```
$_POST['exclude'] = preg_replace( '/' . preg_quote( $match[1], '/' ) . '/', "", $_POST['exclude'], 1, $i );
```

The variable after the $_POST['exclude'] is a `limit` variable, as you can see in the link above.

The [preg_quote()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function wasn't necessary in the date field, but because its a variable, it may be needed to include the special regular expression characters.

Comment: Kerry, you might want to provide the `$delimiter` parameter for `preg_quote`, just in case... as well as actually call `preg_replace`.

Comment: Good point -- thanks. I find it funny/sad that I didn't replace the code with preg_replace